# How to map a property that has its own table in entity core 8?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this Database:

- Order(Id, OrderNumber, State...)
- Client(Id, Name, Surname...)

And I have this entities:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id;
    public string OrderNumber;

    Client Customer;

    //another properties
}

public class Client
{
    public long Id;
    public string Name;

    //Another properties.
}
```

I would like to map with fluent API this relationship in entity core, but I wouldn't like to oned properties, because in the documentation it is said that navigation properties are includes always, I would like to have the option to inlcude it or not according to the sitaution.

If the Order type would have a property for the Id, likes, like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id;
    public string OrderNumber;

    public long IdCustomer;
    public Client Customer;

    //another properties
}
```

I would map the relationship in this way:

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder paramOrderConfiguration)
{
paramOrderConfiguration.ToTable("Orders");

```
paramOrderConfiguration.HasKey(o => o.Id);

paramOrderConfiguration.Property<long>(o => o.Id)
    .HasColumnName("Id")
    .HasColumnType("bigint")
    .IsRequired()
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

}

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CLient> paramClientConfiguration)
{
    paramClientConfiguration.ToTable("CLients");

    paramClientConfiguration.HasKey(o => o.Id);

    paramClientConfiguration.Property<long>(o => o.Id)
        .HasColumnName("Id")
        .HasColumnType("bigint")
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    paramClientConfiguration
        .HasMany<Order>()
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdCustomer);
}
```

But I was thinking that if I have the navigation property for the client, why to have a property for the ID too, if it is included in the Client class?

Is it possible to map the relationship with fluent API without using owned properties and without using a property for the ID in the Order class?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't NEED to have a FK key property on each entity.  EF will add one as a shadow property for each navigation property, if you haven't supplied one yourself.  If the default conventions need changing then you will need to do some thing similar to your example, to control the column name or type.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is true, I can configure the foreign key as shadow property. Thanks so much.